# Firefox stuck in redirect loop(does NOT follow header Location)

Tags: django, firefox, redirect

I can login and logout to the system and it works fine, to reproduce it I need to do the following steps:

GET /
POST / (login data)
-Response: Location /painel
GET /painel/
At this point I'm logged in, then manually:
GET /
-Response: Location /painel (server redirects me back to dashboard, since i'm logged in already)
Now I'm gonna try to logout
GET /logout
-Response: Location /
GET /painel
-Response: Location /
GET /painel
-Response: Location /

At this point I'm stuck in the loop, server keeps sending Location / and firefox redirects to /painel.
Here is firebug screenshot.
[image: ?]

Why is firefox doing this?

Comment: You can safely assume that Firefox is doing nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: It seems that either at some point you've returned a status code 302 (permanent redirect which the browser will cache) or that your logout page doesn't work.

Comment: @benjaoming According to RFC 1945, 302 status code stands for "Moved temporarily" and 301 as "Moved permanently". My logout page works fine with any other browser, and also seem to be working fine with Firefox on Windows. Not sure yet about what's happening.

Comment: Meh, yes, same meaning, though.. 301=permanent, 302=moved. Try deleting your cache in case you had a permanent redirect at some point that still haunting.